# rsync insists on including 'Library' in Mac OS

Tags: rsync, macos-ventura

I'm on MAC OS Ventura 13.1. I created the following filter file for rsync, and saved it as `rsync_filter.conf`.

```
+ */
+ Documents/***
+ Music/***
+ Pictures/***
+ Work/***
- *
```

Then, I call

```
rsync -avm --delete --filter="merge rsync_filter.conf" /Users/Me /Volumes/Backup
```

It does backup the directories I specified, but it also syncs `/Users/Me/Library`, complaining about denied permissions while doing so. I does not sync any other directories, but content of `Library` appears in the backup.

What is so special about `Library` and how do I stop it from syncing? Even including `- Library/*` in the filter file doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was going on. The only files copied from `Library` contained either `Documents` or `Pictures` in their pathway. I preceded my selection of folders in the filter file with my username (e.g. `+ Me/Documents/***` and it solved the problem.

rsync still tries to access `Library` which leads to an warning

```
building file list ... rsync: opendir "/Users/Me/Library/NGL" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

but apart from this it works fine.